# Regarding node.js and npm libraries portability

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, portability

If I write a Javascript code using node.js and libraries installed with npm (e.g. xlsx-populate), will I be able to run the code on a different computer which has none of them installed?

Thanks

Comment: You can use container orchestration tool such as Docker for portability

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about containers. I'm learning about Docker, but before getting deep in the topic I'm trying to understand whether Docker will let me have my application run on the second comupter without the needs of any installation on it. Is this the case? Again, thanks for your time and sorry to bother with noob question, I just can't find this answer anywere :)

Comment: "without the needs of any installation on it" - you must install some program in order for your node.js application to run. Even for Docker, you have to install it on the other computer so that the container can actually setup the environment for you without the need of you installing every single software like node.js, mongodb etc. In this case, it can be a single installation of one software which will allow you to run any application built in it without setting up any environment. Hope that clarifies :)

Comment: definitely, thanks a lot :)
unfortunately I will have to go another way and leave node.js or npm apart, still you're help was really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Every time you install a package using npm, it will be added into the `package.json` . Then the next time if you want to run in other machine, just need tu run the `npm install`